# WPF RibbonComboBox items listed vertically

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I am working on some XAML where I have a RibbonComboBox:

```
<RibbonComboBox SelectionBoxWidth="150" Grid.Row="0">
    <RibbonGallery SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUtilityRun, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <RibbonGalleryCategory ItemsSource="{Binding UtilityRunLabels}" />
    </RibbonGallery>
</RibbonComboBox>
```

When it displays, it shows the items horizontally rather than vertically as I expected:
[image]

How do I style it to place the items vertically?

Comment: Can I ask where you got the documentation about how to use the RibbonComboBox? I can't seem to get anything to work. Also, do you happen to know if there's any way to manually populate it from code? (I posted my own question on this but got no answer.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember where I got it beyond MSDN.  I don't know how you'd populate it from code using the code behind of the control.  We use MVVM with all our WPF work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting [`RibbonGallery.MaxColumnCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbongallery.maxcolumncount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to 1:

```
<RibbonGallery ... MaxColumnCount="1">
```

Answer (score 3):

Set ItemsPanel in Style and Set Orientation=Vertical

```
<Style TargetType="RibbonComboBox">
<Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
<Setter.Value>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: This did not work.  It created a stack panel within the item list that was centered horizontally; the items within the stack panel were horizontally laid out.  Unfortunately I can't post a picture here.

Comment: Sorry If it havent worked . I havent ever used or worked with Ribbon Controls .But this is the way I set ItemPanel in Itemscontrol